# How to export the DDL of domains(Database schema) of new version for update

Tags: grails, grails-orm, database-migration

I have developed a application with `Grails` earlier.Now as per new requirement there is a need to modify the existing `domain classes` as well as adding a new classes and changing / establishing new relationship between the as well.

Now the new requirement has been implemented  and I am going to deploy to production environment. however, the DBA want a script change the production database DDL. DBA is not allowing the `auto create / update` of `database schema` while bootstrapping the application.

I know how to export DDL of for creating tables. but that script will drop tables which means all data will be lost.
But I don't know how to export DDL for DDL-update (no drop tables/recreate tables). Anybody has good suggestion ?

Comment: Even if you migrate the `Database schema` , you won't be able to save the  production data easily as you are saying that there will be addition of new `Domain Classes` and also there will be change in the existing `Domain classes` along with the change in there `relationship`

Comment: Is there any change in the existing `Domain classes`?If yes, what type of changes has been made to them, like `added / removed constraints` etc?Is there any change with `relationship /  mapping` for the existing `Domain classes`?

Comment: Some of the existed domain classes have new fields, and the relavent constraints will be of course added such as index, nullable, unique, etc. I know it will be very easy to let Grails handle DDL update. But the DBA, just as you said, wants to know what tables, what fields, what constraints I change/add/remove. and moreover, because in production environment, the db user id which my system uses has no authorization to ALTER/CREATE tables/constraints/fields. Only the DBA has the authority.

Comment: You want the existing production data as well, right?

Comment: yes. I wanna keep the data in production database cause the system is an on-line system

Comment: You can not expect the existing data to get stored according to the new database schema.For example, you have a table `Sample` with the `contactNumber` field with the `nullable : true` constraint in your `existing schema` and in your `new schema` this constraint has been changed to `nullable : true` & `unique :  true`.In such cases database will fail to keep the existing data intact or adapt to new schema.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not expect the existing data to get stored according to the new database schema as is.**

For example, you have a table Sample with the `contactNumber` `field` with the `nullable : true` constraint in your existing `schema` and in your `new schema` this constraint has been changed to `nullable : true` & `unique : true`.
In such cases database will fail to keep the existing data intact or adapt to new schema.

**To preserve the existing data, you may have to go through a tedious process like -**

1. Take backup of the existing database.
2. Make a note of the modification you have made to the existing `Domain classes`.
3. Find out which modifications may lead to failure / data loss.
4. Drop the earlier `database schema` & Deploy the new application and  let it create the `database schema`.
5. Write a `script`  or `utility` which will process & store the data from `database backup` according to new database schema.Make sure the `utility` you have written has the capalibility to handle the modification(constraint, field added, field removed) done to the `database schema`.